# How to recover tmp folder and problems with apt lockfile

Tags: apt, filesystem, tmp

I accidentally deleted tmp folder. than I was unable to visit browser neither could update/upgrade from terminal. I somehow managed to give 777 permissions to tmp. but When running sudo apt-get upgrade. producing following error.

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Processing triggers for libreoffice-common (1:4.2.8-0ubuntu3) ...
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the download directory
E: Problem executing scripts DPkg::Post-Invoke 'apt-get clean'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Comment: The correct permissions are `sudo chmod 1777 /tmp`.

Answer (score 4):

To recreate /tmp you need to do the following:

```
mkdir /tmp 
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

But

```
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

has nothing to do with /tmp. See [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)

Comment: But I am facing this problem since I deleted tmp folder. then IDK how the tmp folder recreated.  I have given 777 permissions to tmp. It start allowing me to open browser run commands update/upgrade but giving above mentioned errors. So I guess it is related to tmp folder.
Thanks for help btw

Comment: But after the tmp/  was created again the problem probably did not go away ;) so follow the link